# Why does C require pointer dereferencing here?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

Here is a little C program that generates the following:

> warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing.
> 'int' with an expression of type 'int *'; dereference with *

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
typedef struct node {
  int arr[N];
} node;

node *new_node(int arr[N]) {
  node *x = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  *x = (node){arr};
  return x;
}

int main() {
  int arr[N] = {0, 1, 2};
  node *x = new_node(arr);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", x->arr[i]);
}
```

Dereferencing as `*x = (node){*arr};` resolves the warning but the program does not produce the expected output.

My C is a bit rusty but, as I understand, whenever you pass an array to a function you essentially pass a pointer to its first element.

Therefore, the above should be the same as the following program (which works as expected):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
typedef struct node {
  int *arr;
} node;

node *new_node(int *arr) {
  node *x = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  *x = (node){arr};
  return x;
}

int main() {
  int arr[N] = {0, 1, 2};
  node *x = new_node(arr);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", x->arr[i]);
}
```

What C detail do I not have right here?

Comment: You cannot initialize an array (`node`'s `arr[N]`) with a pointer.

Comment: Don't cast void * from malloc in c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *whenever you pass an array to a function you essentially pass a pointer to its first element*

This is correct; the two functions, `foo(int a[])` and `foo(int* a)` are, to all intents and purposes, identical.

> *the above should be the same as this program*

However, this is *not* correct. The different argument type for the `new_node` function (`int arr[N]` *vs* `int *arr`) is **not the only difference** between the two code snippets: there is also a significant difference in the `node` structure.

In the second snippet, the first member of that `struct` is an `int*`, and casting a structure to the type of its first member (and *vice versa*) is valid C; however, in the first snippet, there is no pointer in the structure (an array is *not* a pointer, even though, in many expressions, it 'decays' to a pointer to its first element).

In your first snippet, the first member of the structure (that is to say, the type of the data at the starting address of that structure) is actually the **first element of the array**. So, when you do, `*x = (node){ arr };` the `arr` identifier decays to a pointer but the cast and the LHS of the assignment refer to the location of an `int`.

To set the values of the array member of your structure, you would need to: *either* copy the memory pointed to by the argument into the structure; *or* initialize the allocated `node` using a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) constructed from the elements of the pointed-to array:

```c
node* new_node(int arr[N]) // Version using the "memcpy" function
{
    node* x = malloc(sizeof(node));
    memcpy(x, arr, sizeof(int) * N);
    return x;
}

node* new_node(int arr[N]) // Version using a compound literal
{
    node* x = malloc(sizeof(node));
    *x = (node){ { arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] } };
    return x;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a 'hybrid' between your two code snippets: have the `int arr[N]` argument to `new_node` (as in your first case) but use an `int *arr` member of the `struct node` (as in your second case). That will then work as expected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
typedef struct node {
    int *arr;
} node;

node* new_node(int arr[N]) // The "N" is now redundant
{
    node* x = malloc(sizeof(node));
    *x = (node){ arr }; // Member pointer is assigned value of passed pointer
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[N] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    node* x = new_node(arr); // Address is passed
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", x->arr[i]); // Works!
    }
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe give an example of how to use the initializer?  `(node) {arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]}`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Does the `memcpy` approach do the exact same thing as the "hybrid" approach?  I suppose not?  It seems that in the `memcpy` approach we actually make a copy of the array pointed to by `arr[N]` while in the hybrid approach we simply just store the pointer `arr[N]` itself?

Comment: @scribe They do not do the same thing. As you said, the `memcpy` (and compound literal) approach makes a copy of the data into the structure's own array memory. The 'hybrid' approach just copies a pointer to the *original* data. Just like you say.

Comment: In your example, the second is safe, because that original data array stays alive for the duration of the program. However, if the node were being created from another function called by `main`, then it would fail, because the 'original' data would go out of scope and the array's lifetime would end (a so-called "dangling pointer").

Comment: Could you maybe show if and how the `memcpy` approach changes if the array is not the first and only member of the struct?

Comment: The whole point is that the `node` structures are very different in your two snippets.

Comment: @scribe With a significant change to the nature of the `node` structure, I think this becomes a (very) different question. Let's try to avoid moving goalposts and/or mission-creep.

Comment: I understand, should I ask a new question?  Or maybe point me to another resource?

Comment: @Scribe To be honest, I can't see how your new question would really relate to this one. Passing a structure by pointer is one thing and passing an array is another. In this case, there is considerable overlap.

Comment: I just meant (now that I know) when `arr` is not the first element of the `node`, we change your `memcpy(x, arr, sizeof(int) * N);` to `memcpy(x->arr, arr, sizeof(int) * N);`.

Comment: @scribe Yeah, that's how you would do it.